# C# Generics for returning multiple types from a method

Tags: c#, generics, return-type

the idea is to make a method which can return different types, in my case array of strings,  stack of strings and list of strings.

This is the hypotetical code:

```
static <T> TestMethod<T>(string [] test,int option)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1://Return array of strings
        return test;

        case 2:
        return new List<string>(test);

        case 3:
        return new Stack<string>(test);
    }
}
```

I input a list of strings, and get in output what I need, by specifying an option.

Now, that code gives load of errorsm and other answers on stackoverflow are all fuzzy and confusing, so I avoided them (I've tried to read like 10 of them and not a single one was clear and all were giving compilation errors)

From what I've understood one error is that I can't simply do

```
static <T> TestMethod<T>
```

because I need to declare in some way what T is (string, list etc).

No, I want to return what I like. I've saw someone using Convert.ChangeType, but I want to know what in your opinion is the best solution for this situation.

Comment: `I want to return what I like` No you can't. At best you can return `IEnumerable<T>` common to array,list & stack.

Comment: The best solution in this situation is hard to determine, because it's not clear what actual problem you are trying to solve. How is a method that can return arbitrary stuff useful?

Comment: I thought about returning IEnumerable interface as I saw in other answers they were suggesting interfaces use. Problem is I have a particular hate for interfaces (see my other questions) as I don't know how to do with an enumerable and I don't know how to use interfaces and never understood them.

@JeroenMostert The method would have to return a list of folders or files with Directory.GetDirectories or GetFiles and return the in the desired output format

Answer (score 2):

At this point your method is not generic since it does nothing with the `T` parameter - one option is to make the output type a type that is compatible with all of the possible return values (with your example your choices are `ICollection`, `IEnumerable`, and `IEnumerable<string>`):

```
static IEnumerable<string> TestMethod(string [] test,int option)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1://Return array of strings
        return test;

        case 2:
        return new List<string>(test);

        case 3:
        return new Stack<string>(test);
    }
}
```

If you want to make the first parameter generic you could do:

```
static IEnumerable<T> TestMethod<T>(T [] test,int option)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1://Return array of strings
        return test;

        case 2:
        return new List<T>(test);

        case 3:
        return new Stack<T>(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I hate interfaces, never understood why they are useful and never needed them, but I guess I'll have to live with them, sigh... So, once I get out of the method, how I'll use my IEnumerable? What is it? Like a List? Like a Stack? Like what?

Comment: "never understood why they are useful and never needed them" is a chicken and egg problem. You should trust the body of evidence around you that the concept of interfaces is both worth understanding and useful, and you may want to add generics to the list of useful things you should consider learning more about.

Comment: `user2235691 Ok. I hate interfaces, never understood why they are useful and never needed them, but I guess I'll have to live with them` just because you don't understand it does not make it bad It's really worth reading up on something like this especially `IEnumberable` it's saved my life many times.. :) good luck

Comment: @user2235691 You said `I want to return what I like` So asking this is silly `What is it? Like a List? Like a Stack? Like what?` It can be any one of them. You have to *cast* it to correct type to use specific methods of those classes.

Comment: I know what you are saying. Believe me, I tried to read about interfaces hundreds of times and never  got what's so cool about it. I even made a question trying to ask for explanation and I got nothing out of it.... I can't understand what they are for... Any help is appreciated

Comment: MSDN has lots of examples and explanation on C# and Interfaces for some coders it's something that either clicks when they first read it or doesn't kind of like COM when it first came out vs Interop reading and practice will enlighten your understanding respectfully speaking.. now are there other ways of doing things without using Interfaces...?? Yes I guess it becomes one of those pick your poison type things and I mean poison in a positive way..

Comment: Well, tried the interface thing, it solved the problem, but it gets out an IEnumerable object which is a horrible frankenstein of unusable methods and intelligible gibberish. 

Well, I guess I'll make a method with a different return type for every object type I need (one method for array, one for list and one for stack)

Comment: @user2235691 `IEnumerable<T>` allows you to use `foreach` and Linq queries against generic collections. Do some research on Linq and you should have no problem using `IEnumerable<T>`.